# web.config rule for 301 redirection

Tags: c#, web-config

My site is in html and all the files are placed now in httpdocs directory my urls are coming like .

```
http://Mysite.com/httpdocs/test.html and i need to show
http://Mysite.com/test.html
```

in my google custom search .
I have used 301 redirection in web.config just like

```
<location path="httpdocs/test.html">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="/test.html " exactDestination="true" childOnly="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

and its working for around 750 urls but i have 1500 urls and i think this is out of limit of web.config so please let me know some best suggestion or if i can write some rule in one line for it then it will be fine .

Comment: Do you use iis 7.5 and do you have admin access to server?

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done if you host you App on IIS 7.5 and can install [URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite):

```
    <system.webServer>    
        <rewrite>
            <rule name="Stop" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^httpdocs/" />
                <action type="AbortRequest"/>
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rewrite">
                <match url=".*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="httpdocs/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rewrite>    
    </system.webServer>
```

Comment: is this possible without URL Rewrite module?

Comment: i have used url rewriting module 2.0 and used above rule but in the address bar it is showing me the url like http://Mysite.com/httpdocs/test.html

Comment: now it is working with both the urls  http://Mysite.com/httpdocs/test.html  and  http://Mysite.com/test.html and i need to allow only http://Mysite.com/test.html

Comment: Modified my answer. Please check it one more time

Comment: 500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18978/discussion-between-uriil-and-novicetodotnet)